# What determines the effect of a craft?

Tags: oh-edo-towns

When I use a craft on a person/house, it can:

- Increase their yield
- Increase their wallet
- Increase both
- Have no effect

What determines the outcome (and the amount of increase, if there is one)?

Answer (score 1):

There are several factors.

First, crafts are more effective on certain buildings. In other Kairosoft games these are pretty explicit, while here they are less obvious. Logical choices will generally be more effective though.

Second, crafts have specific categories that they affect. A craft used on the correct building will enhance all of those categories, while one used on a sub-optimal building may affect none or only one characteristic.

Third, the higher a building is upgraded, the more difficult it becomes to further improve it. Therefore, its advisable to spread upgrades out for maximum efficiency.

In general, patterns are easy to determine through just playing games, since they are fairly logical in what they develop. An expensive sounding item is likely to boost wealth for example.

If you are still having trouble, try playing some of the other kairosoft games, particuarly Dungeon town. In dungeon town, the categories are specifically shown by color coding, so you can get an idea of what items match what. (plus dungeon town is one of the more unique games).

Comment: While this is somewhat useful, an authoritative answer would include the various crafts' affected categories and compatible buildings. Right now, you're pretty much just saying "it's intuitive", which may or may not be true, depending on the individual gamer.